# Android RatingBar change star colors

Tags: android, rating

How can I change the star colors and size of the stars?

Comment: I think you have to create your own custom rating bar if you want to do that

Comment: I wrote a blog post describing how to change RatingBar images: http://kozyr.zydako.net/2010/05/23/pretty-ratingbar/ It also shows where you can specify image size...

Comment: I was hoping this question is for multicolored rating bar as shown in websites, couldn't find one for myself. Created a simple implementation myself https://github.com/codebreaker/coloredratingbar-android . Hope this helps someone out there.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Step #1: Create your own style, by cloning one of the existing styles (from `$ANDROID_HOME/platforms/$SDK/data/res/values/styles.xml`), putting it in your own project's `styles.xml`, and referencing it when you add the widget to a layout.

Step #2: Create your own `LayerDrawable` XML resources for the `RatingBar`, pointing to appropriate images to use for the bar. The original styles will point you to the existing resources that you can compare with. Then, adjust your style to use your own `LayerDrawable` resources, rather than built-in ones.

Comment: As per step #2, This doesn't work for Samsung 3 devices or some others, this isn't required to be a LayerDrawable. See here for info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30266334/cannot-cast-to-layerdrawable-anymore-after-upgrading-v7

Comment: Use android:progressTint="@color/yellow". See @superpuccio 's answer.

Comment: progressTint supported only above 21 api level

Comment: This is the best solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36297738/1935135

Answer (score 122):

It's a little complicated at the mentioned blog, I've used a similar but simplier way.
You do need 3 star images (red_star_full.png, red_star_half.png and red_star_empty.png) and one xml, that's all.

Put these 3 images at res/drawable.

Put there the following ratingbar_red.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background" android:drawable="@drawable/red_star_empty" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress" android:drawable="@drawable/red_star_half" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress" android:drawable="@drawable/red_star_full" />
</layer-list>
```

and, finally, tell your ratingbar definition to use this, i.e.

```
<RatingBar android:progressDrawable="@drawable/ratingbar_red"/>
```

That's it.

Comment: Hi Alex, I've tried this solution but when I try to set the rating to something like 1.1, 1.2, etc... it's display as 1.5. I have taken 3 star images, one empty, one half full and one full. I presume it's supposed to interpolate between them to get the fractional components, I'm just wondering has anyone else had the same issue or am I doing something noticeably wrong?

Comment: Can you please tel me about the images we should use weather its a colored images and size of images im not able to solve this...

Comment: Everybody see that 2015 update answer below! It's much easier and simpler!

Comment: This answer still provides more flexibility over the different states of the stars.

Comment: Why I'm getting vertical lines below stars? I tried defining custom style, specifying height, but there is still vertical lines below stars on my AVD.

Comment: can i have the every star have a different color like first star have red color second star have a blue color  third star have yellow and last star have a green color it is possible ?

Answer (score 94):

Try this, if you only want to change color:

```
RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
stars.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Comment: What exactly does `PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP` mean or do?

Comment: Doesn't work on API 5.0 and up. Needs: ```Drawable stars = rb.getProgressDrawable();  stars.setTint( Color.YELLOW ); ```

Comment: @zyamys This really sucks =( A method for "higher versions" and another method for older versions is necessary?

Comment: It only works for a precision of 0.5. Otherwise (precision < 0.5)  the overlay gets weird and seems like the blue color is still with a precision of 0.5 while the yellow is precise

Comment: This behavior happened on an Android 5.0 btw

Comment: Warning: Crashes on pre-lolipop devices. Go with the accepted answer.

Comment: Working fine on Galaxy Nexus 4.2.1 Jelly Bean

Comment: stars.getDrawable(2) : why it is stars.getDrawable(2) means why index is 2?

Comment: yes, as far as i remember, getDrawable returns drawable at specific index, since rating bar is a bit complex view, it has multiple drawables.

Answer (score 74):

The easiest way that worked for me...if you are extending AppCompat Activity

In your build.gradle add latest appcompat library.

```
dependencies {  
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:X.X.X' // where X.X.X version
}
```

Make your activity extend android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {  
    ...
}
```

Declare custom style in your styles.xml file.

```
<style name="RatingBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat">  
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/indigo</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/pink</item>
</style>
```

Apply this style to your RatingBar via android:theme attribute.

```
<RatingBar  
    android:theme="@style/RatingBar"
    android:rating="3"
    android:stepSize="0.5"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Thanks @Vishal Kumar. I tried it on Kitkat 4.4.4 (Samsung S3 neo) and Marshmallow 6.0.1 (Samsung Galaxy On Nxt) , it worked. But no success on Lollipop 5.1(Micromax). For Lollipop I used the "android:progressTint" attribute in RatingBar and yes it works.

Comment: That's the best solution.

Comment: This should be the selected correct answer.

Comment: This is the best solution. If you want to change the star size, you can use `style="?android:ratingBarStyleSmall"` together.

Comment: @AndréLuizReis  `<style name="RatingBarSmallTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorOrangeNormal</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorOrangeActivated</item>
        <item name="ratingBarStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small</item>
    </style>`

and your ratingBar

`android:theme="@style/RatingBarSmallTheme"`

Answer (score 53):

**From the API 21** on it's very easy to change the color of the stars with this three lines of code:

```
android:progressTint="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
android:progressBackgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
android:secondaryProgressTint="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
```

Doing it like this, you'll change:

- the filled stars color (progressTint)
- the unfilled stars color (progressBackgroundTint)
- and the border color (secondaryProgressTint) of the stars

Comment: Instead of 3.5 it paints 4 stars.

Comment: @CoolMind set android:stepSize:1 instead of 0.5

Comment: How to change the color of an empty star?

Comment: @winklerrr did you find solution how to change the colour of an empty star.

Comment: Didn't do further checks to find a solution

Answer (score 47):

**2015 Update**

Now you can use [DrawableCompat](http://%09android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableCompat) to tint all kind of drawables. For example:

```
Drawable progress = ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
DrawableCompat.setTint(progress, Color.WHITE);
```

This is backwards compatible up to API 4

Comment: Don't forget to set the drawable back on the ratingBar.

Comment: This tints the entire drawable into one color which makes the empty stars very hard to distinguish.

Comment: This works only with android support library >=22 and not with support library <22.

Comment: Yes, but support library >= 22 is available to everyone and backwards compatible up to API 4. I don't see any problem there

Comment: @Terence, that is not needed.

Comment: working on lollipop but not working with 4.4.4 kitakat.....

Comment: It draws 5 colored stars, not 3.5.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31739778/2914140 as an extension to this solution.

Comment: I would just surround that with `if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {}` since it is working by default from API 22.

Answer (score 37):

If you want to change color for all stars states you my use:

```
LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
stars.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.starFullySelected), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
stars.getDrawable(1).setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.starPartiallySelected), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
stars.getDrawable(0).setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.starNotSelected), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Comment: Is there any ways to set the stars color based on the data fetched from database? Let's say I got 5 stars and the data returned from database was 4. So instead of changing all 5, I only change the first 4

Comment: getColor is deprecated now, any alternative?

Comment: You may find answers here http://stackoverflow.com/a/32202256/2513291 For example this approach ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_name)

Comment: works well, but notice that, for some reason, the order is important (2, then 1, then 0). I tried the reverse and it lead to some UI glitches the first time the color is changed.

Answer (score 25):

The solutions that Alex and CommonsWares have posted are correct. One thing that the Android never talks about though is proper pixel sizes for different densities. Here are the required dimensions for each density based on halo light.

**Small Star**

```
mdpi: 16px
hdpi: 24px
xhdpi: 32px
xxhdpi: 48px
```

**Medium Star**

```
mdpi: 24px
hdpi: 36px
xhdpi: 48px
xxhdpi: 72px
```

**Large Star**

```
mdpi: 35px
hdpi: 52px
xhdpi: 69px
xxhdpi: 105px
```

Comment: can I use vectordrawble with stars

Answer (score 25):

So I have been struggling with this issue for two hours and I have come up with a working solution for all API versions, where half stars ratings are also shown.

```
private void setRatingStarColor(Drawable drawable, @ColorInt int color)
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    {
        DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, color);
    }
    else
    {
        drawable.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    }
}
```

You call the method with this order of drawables:

```
    LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
    // Filled stars
    setRatingStarColor(stars.getDrawable(2), ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.foreground));
    // Half filled stars
    setRatingStarColor(stars.getDrawable(1), ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.background));
    // Empty stars
    setRatingStarColor(stars.getDrawable(0), ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.background));
```

NOTE: Also you must specify attributes "max" and "numStars" in XML, otherwise half stars aren't shown.

Comment: the only way that works for me on API19, but I haven't given up to look for a way doing this from xml only T_T

Comment: @BeeingJk if you create a custom view that extends RatingBar you can create your own xml attributes to specify the tint color. You then have a single point of control for setting the tint and can specify the tint in xml. Hope that helps! Can explain more if needed

Comment: `Mode.SRC_IN` or `Mode.MULTIPLY` ?

Answer (score 13):

Now you can use [DrawableCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompat.html#setTint%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20int%29) from AppCompat v22.1.0 onwards to dynamically tint all kind of drawables, useful when you're supporting multiple themes with a single set of drawables. For example:

```
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
DrawableCompat.setTint(DrawableCompat.wrap(layerDrawable.getDrawable(0)), Color.RED);   // Empty star
DrawableCompat.setTint(DrawableCompat.wrap(layerDrawable.getDrawable(1)), Color.GREEN); // Partial star
DrawableCompat.setTint(DrawableCompat.wrap(layerDrawable.getDrawable(2)), Color.BLUE);  // Full star
```

This is backwards compatible down to API 4. Also see Chris Banes' blog post on [Support Libraries v22.1.0](https://chris.banes.me/2015/04/22/support-libraries-v22-1-0/)

For the actual size and shape you will need to define a new style and layer-list drawables for the appropriate size, as others have already answered above.

Comment: Drawables are not arrays how are you accessing progress[0]?

Comment: @blueice You're right sorry, Drawable should be a LayerDrawable, corrected now, thanks.

Comment: Still did not seem to work for me, I ended up with what Yuriy Vinogradov put in a different response to this question and that seems to work.

Comment: How to change Drawable instead Change color ?

Comment: @ImanMarashi See Alex's XML based answer above, [LayerDrawable.setDrawable(index, drawable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html#setDrawable%28int,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) is only available from API23 onwards.

Answer (score 10):

For just changing the color of Rating bar from xml:-

```
android:progressTint="@color/your_color"
android:backgroundTint="@color/your_color"
android:secondaryProgressTint="@color/your_color"
```

Comment: it doesn't change empty star color

Answer (score 10):

Use `android:theme` attribute:

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="Theme.Rating" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/rating</item>
</style>
```

**layout.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRatingBar
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Rating"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 7):

To change the color you just have to put set the parameter android:progressTint

```
 <RatingBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:rating="1"
        android:progressTint="@android:/color/black"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
       />
```

For the size the style property.

Comment: works only on API 21 or higher , thanks

Answer (score 6):

The simpliest way:

```
android:progressTint="@color/color"
```

Comment: Note that this only works on api 21+

Answer (score 5):

Withou adding a new style you can use the tint color within the `RatingBar`

```
             <RatingBar
                    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
                    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.RatingBar.Small"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:numStars="5"
                    android:rating="4.5"
                    android:stepSize="0.5"
                    android:progressTint="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Building @lgvalle's answer.

> 2015 Update
>
> Now you can use DrawableCompat to tint all kind of drawables. For example:
>
> Drawable progress = ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
>      DrawableCompat.setTint(progress, Color.WHITE);
>   This is backwards compatible up to API 4

```
LayerDrawable drawable = (LayerDrawable) getProgressDrawable();
Drawable progress = drawable.getDrawable(2);
DrawableCompat.setTint(progress, getResources().getColor(COLOR1));
progress = drawable.getDrawable(1);
DrawableCompat.setTintMode(progress, PorterDuff.Mode.DST_ATOP);
DrawableCompat.setTint(progress, getResources().getColor(COLOR1));
DrawableCompat.setTintMode(progress, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
DrawableCompat.setTint(progress, getResources().getColor(COLOR2));
progress = drawable.getDrawable(0);
DrawableCompat.setTint(progress, getResources().getColor(COLOR2));
```

This will keep the fraction steps colors.

Answer (score 4):

```
<!--For rating bar -->
    <style name="RatingBarfeed" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
```

use your own color

Answer (score 4):

#### Works for Android below and above version 21

After some research I've come up with this method to set the background tint, the gap tint (ex: half star) and the star tint color.

```
LayerDrawable layers = (LayerDrawable) ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
DrawableCompat.setTint(layers.getDrawable(0), 0x33000000); // The background tint
DrawableCompat.setTint(layers.getDrawable(1), 0x00000000); // The gap tint (Transparent in this case so the gap doesnt seem darker than the background)
DrawableCompat.setTint(layers.getDrawable(2), 0xffFED80A); // The star tint
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution, use **AppCompatRatingBar** and its **setProgressTintList** method to achieve this, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51673325/3094917) for reference.

Comment: This worked for me under API 28 using com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha02

Answer (score 2):

I solve this issue this following:

```
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();

DrawableCompat.setTint(DrawableCompat.wrap(layerDrawable.getDrawable(0)),
                       Color.WHITE);  // Empty star
DrawableCompat.setTint(DrawableCompat.wrap(layerDrawable.getDrawable(1)),
                       Color.YELLOW); // Partial star
DrawableCompat.setTint(DrawableCompat.wrap(layerDrawable.getDrawable(2)),
                       Color.YELLOW);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But for fractional rating stars are painted wholly.

Answer (score 2):

```
RatingBar mRating=(RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.rating);
 LayerDrawable layerDrawable=(LayerDrawable)mRating.getProgressDrawable();
 layerDrawable.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(Color.parseColor
 ("#32CD32"),    PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

for me its working....

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple solution for changing the color of the star according to your theme.

Goto this site : http://android-holo-colors.com/

Choose your theme color and get your star images created.

Answer (score 1):

Using the answers above, I created a quick static method that can easily be re-used. It only aims at tinting the progress color for the activated stars. The stars that are not activated remain grey.

```
    public static RatingBar tintRatingBar (RatingBar ratingBar, int progressColor)if (ratingBar.getProgressDrawable() instanceof LayerDrawable) {
        LayerDrawable progressDrawable = (LayerDrawable) ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
        Drawable drawable = progressDrawable.getDrawable(2);
        Drawable compat = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
        DrawableCompat.setTint(compat, progressColor);
        Drawable[] drawables = new Drawable[3];
        drawables[2] = compat;

        drawables[0] = progressDrawable.getDrawable(0);
        drawables[1] = progressDrawable.getDrawable(1);

        LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(drawables);

        ratingBar.setProgressDrawable(layerDrawable);

        return ratingBar;
    }
    else {
        Drawable progressDrawable =  ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
        Drawable compat = DrawableCompat.wrap(progressDrawable);
        DrawableCompat.setTint(compat, progressColor);
        ratingBar.setProgressDrawable(compat);
        return ratingBar;
    }
}
```

Just pass your rating bar and a Color using `getResources().getColor(R.color.my_rating_color)`

As you can see, I use DrawableCompat so it's backward compatible.

EDIT : This method does not work on API21 (go figure why). You end up with a NullPointerException when calling setProgressBar. I ended up disabling the whole method on API >= 21.

For API >= 21, I use SupperPuccio solution.

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapperHoneycomb cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable 

on pre-lollipop

Comment: @IshaanGarg you are right. I ran into the same issue and updated my method. I updated my code to handle the case. I don't think it is a matter of android version. If you use the smaller version of the rating bar (with style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"), then the drawable returned is still a LayoutDrawable.

Comment: Yup, just what I had implemented, just be sure to use AppCompatRatingBar. Though I'm not able to get half star when pre-setting the rating from XML/java. Like setRating(3.5) shows 4 full stars

Answer (score 1):

The rating bar is used automatically at run time for change color on touch star.

First add style in app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml file:

```
<style name="RatingBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/com_facebook_blue</item>
</style>
```

Then your rating bar add theme like this:

```
<RatingBar
   android:id="@+id/rating"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:numStars="5"
   android:stepSize="1"
   android:theme="@style/RatingBar"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

1)  declare this xml

```
<LinearLayout 
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:paddingLeft="20dp"
         android:paddingRight="20dp"
         android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
         android:background="#323232"
         android:gravity="center_horizontal">

       <com.example.android.custom_ratingbar.CustomRatingBar
        android:id="@+id/coloredRatingBar5"
        style="@style/coloredRatingBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

         />
       </LinearLayout>
```

2) in style.xml

```
<style name="coloredRatingBarStyleSmall">
        <item name="indicator">false</item>
        <item name="type">small</item>
    </style>
```

3)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class CustomRatingBar extends View{

    private static final String TAG="ColoredRatingBar";
    private static final int NORMAL = 0;
    private static final int SMALL = 1;

    Bitmap[] drawables;
    Bitmap progressBackground;
    Context mContext;
    private int mNumStars =9;
    private float mRating =0;
    private boolean mIndicator;
    private float slidePosition;
    private int mType;

    /**
     * A callback that notifies clients when the rating has been changed. This
     * includes changes that were initiated by the user through a touch gesture
     * or arrow key/trackball as well as changes that were initiated
     * programmatically.
     */
    public interface OnRatingBarChangeListener {

        /**
         * Notification that the rating has changed. Clients can use the
         * fromUser parameter to distinguish user-initiated changes from those
         * that occurred programmatically. This will not be called continuously
         * while the user is dragging, only when the user finalizes a rating by
         * lifting the touch.
         *
         * @param ratingBar The RatingBar whose rating has changed.
         * @param rating The current rating. This will be in the range
         *            0..numStars.
         * @param fromUser True if the rating change was initiated by a user's
         *            touch gesture or arrow key/horizontal trackbell movement.
         */
        void onRatingChanged(CustomRatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser);

    }

    private OnRatingBarChangeListener mOnRatingBarChangeListener;

    public CustomRatingBar(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }
    public CustomRatingBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs,0);//R.attr.coloredRatingBarStyle
    }

    public CustomRatingBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomRatingBar,defStyle, 0);
        final boolean indicator = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.CustomRatingBar_indicator, false);
        final float rating = a.getFloat(R.styleable.CustomRatingBar_setrating, -1);
        final int type = a.getInt(R.styleable.CustomRatingBar_type, 0);
        a.recycle();

        setIndicator(indicator);
        setRating(rating);
        setType(type);
        init(context);
    }

    public int getType() {
        return mType;
    }

    public void setType(int type) {
        this.mType = type;
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        Resources res = getResources();
        if(mType==SMALL){
            drawables = new Bitmap[]{BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.rating_inactive),BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.rating_active)};
            progressBackground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.rating_inactive);
        }else{
            drawables = new Bitmap[]{BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.rating_inactive),BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.rating_active)};
            progressBackground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.rating_inactive);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        //draw empty stars bg
        for(int i=0;i< mNumStars;i++){
            drawStar(canvas,i);
        }

    }


    private void drawStar(Canvas canvas, int position) {
        float fraction = mRating -(position);
        Bitmap ratedStar1 = getRatedStar();
        Paint paint=getPaint(position);
        int division=getSize();
        Bitmap ratedStar=null;
        Bitmap emptyStar=null;
       if(!isInEditMode()){
        ratedStar=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(ratedStar1, division, division, false);
        emptyStar=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(progressBackground, division, division, false);
       }
        if((position)< mRating){
            if(!isInEditMode()){
           canvas.drawBitmap(ratedStar,(position* division),0,paint);
            }

        } else{

                if(!isInEditMode()){
              canvas.drawBitmap(emptyStar,(position*division),0,null);

            }
        }


    }
    private int getSize(){
        return (getWidth()/mNumStars);
    }

    private Bitmap getRatedStar() {

        if(mRating==0){
            return drawables[0];
        }
        else{
            return drawables[1];
        }
    }

    private Paint getPaint(int position){
        int value=(255*(position+1))/mNumStars;
        String hexString=Integer.toHexString(value).equals("0")?"00":Integer.toHexString(value);
        String hexvalue="#"+hexString+"000000";//FEE98E
        //Log.e("TAG", position+"/"+value+"/"+hexvalue);

        Paint paint=new Paint();

        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor(hexvalue));

        return paint;
    }

    public int getNumStars() {
        return mNumStars;
    }

    public void setNumStars(int numStars) {
        this.mNumStars = numStars;
    }

    public float getRating() {
        return mRating;
    }

    public void setRating(float rating) {
        setRating(rating,false);
    }

    void setRating(float rating,boolean fromUser) {
        if(rating>mNumStars){
            this.mRating = mNumStars;
        }
        this.mRating = rating;
        invalidate();
        dispatchRatingChange(fromUser);
    }

    public boolean isIndicator() {
        return mIndicator;
    }

    public void setIndicator(boolean indicator) {
        this.mIndicator = indicator;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        if (progressBackground != null) {

            final int width = progressBackground.getWidth() * mNumStars;
            final int height = progressBackground.getHeight();

            int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            Bitmap emptyStar=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(progressBackground, widthSize/mNumStars, widthSize/mNumStars, false);
            int heightSize = emptyStar.getHeight();

            setMeasuredDimension(resolveSizeAndState(widthSize, widthMeasureSpec, 0),
                    resolveSizeAndState(heightSize, heightMeasureSpec, 0));
        }
        else{
              int desiredWidth = 100;
            int desiredHeight = 50;

            int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
            int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
            int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

            int width;
            int height;

            //Measure Width
            if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
                //Must be this size
                width = widthSize;
            } else if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
                //Can't be bigger than...
                width = Math.min(desiredWidth, widthSize);
            } else {
                //Be whatever you want
                width = desiredWidth;
            }

            //Measure Height
            if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
                //Must be this size
                height = heightSize;
            } else if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
                //Can't be bigger than...
                height = Math.min(desiredHeight, heightSize);
            } else {
                //Be whatever you want
                height = desiredHeight;
            }

            //MUST CALL THIS
          setMeasuredDimension(resolveSizeAndState(width, widthMeasureSpec, 0),resolveSizeAndState(height, heightMeasureSpec, 0));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(mIndicator){
            return false;
        }

        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                slidePosition = getRelativePosition(event.getX());

                int newRating = (int)(slidePosition>0?slidePosition+1:0) ;
                if(newRating>mNumStars){
                    newRating=mNumStars;
                }

             //   Log.e("TAG", ""+newRating);
                if (newRating != mRating) {
                    setRating(newRating,true);
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private float getRelativePosition(float x) {
        Bitmap emptyStar=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(progressBackground, getWidth()/mNumStars, getWidth()/mNumStars, false);
        int widthSize = emptyStar.getWidth();
      //  Log.e("TAG", widthSize+"/"+x);
         float position = x / widthSize;
       position = Math.max(position, 0);
       return Math.min(position, mNumStars);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the listener to be called when the rating changes.
     *
     * @param listener The listener.
     */
    public void setOnRatingBarChangeListener(OnRatingBarChangeListener listener) {
        mOnRatingBarChangeListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * @return The listener (may be null) that is listening for rating change
     *         events.
     */
    public OnRatingBarChangeListener getOnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        return mOnRatingBarChangeListener;
    }

    void dispatchRatingChange(boolean fromUser) {
        if (mOnRatingBarChangeListener != null) {
            mOnRatingBarChangeListener.onRatingChanged(this, getRating(),
                    fromUser);
        }
    }
}


5) then in calling activity---

CustomRatingBar coloredRatingBar5=(CustomRatingBar)findViewById(R.id.coloredRatingBar5);
        coloredRatingBar5.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(CustomRatingBar ratingBar, float rating,boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.e("RATING", ""+rating);

            }
        });
```

6) rating active---take any image with dark color coz it will be used as color transparency for different rating

rating_inactive--take any image of same size of above image with light background..it will used when no rating is selected

Answer (score 0):

A very easy way to change the border colour of the stars is using the xml parameter:

```
android:progressBackgroundTint=""
```

in the ratingBar view. The value should be a hexadecimal code for a color.

Comment: I don't know why, but it seems that you method only affects the border of the stars (the filling color remains the default color)

Comment: Ok, you missed some xml params. Check out my answer here below.

Comment: You're right. I don't know why I was thinking he had problems changing the border colour of the star (maybe because if the problem I had). Your answer is more complete.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a reliable method to do this all the way down to API 9 at least.
The "casting to LayerDrawble" solution seemed like a risky solution to me, and when I tested it out on an Android phone on 2.3, it casted successfully but the call to DrawableCompat.setTint(...) did not have any effect.

The need to load drawable assets did not seem like a good solution to me either.

I decided to code my own solution which is a class extending AppCompatRatingBar, using a custom Drawable taking care of drawing the stars programmatically. It works perfectly for my needs, I'll post it in case it helps anyone:

https://gist.github.com/androidseb/2b8044c90a07c7a52b4bbff3453c8460

The link is easier because you can get the full file directly, but here is the full code just in case:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRatingBar;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

/**
 * @author androidseb
 *         <p/>
 *         Extends AppCompatRatingBar with the ability to tint the drawn stars when selected, pressed and un-selected.
 *         Limitation: Only draws full stars.
 */
public class TintableRatingBar extends AppCompatRatingBar {
    private TintableRatingBarProgressDrawable progressDrawable;

    public TintableRatingBar(final Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public TintableRatingBar(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public TintableRatingBar(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        progressDrawable = new TintableRatingBarProgressDrawable();
        setProgressDrawable(progressDrawable);
    }

    public void setCustomTintColors(final int _uncheckedColor, final int _pressedColor, final int _checkedColor) {
        progressDrawable.setRatingMaxLevelValue(getMax() * 1000);
        progressDrawable.setUnCheckedColor(_uncheckedColor);
        progressDrawable.setPressedColor(_pressedColor);
        progressDrawable.setCheckedColor(_checkedColor);
        invalidate();
    }

    public class TintableRatingBarProgressDrawable extends Drawable {
        private static final int STAR_COUNT = 5;
        private static final int STAR_BRANCHES_COUNT = 5;

        /** Sets the max level value: if the level is at the max, then all stars are selected. */
        private int ratingMaxLevelValue = 10000;
        /** Color to be painted for unselected stars */
        private int uncheckedColor = Color.GRAY;
        /** Color to be painted for unselected stars when the ratingbar is pressed */
        private int pressedColor = Color.CYAN;
        /** Color to be painted for selected stars */
        private int checkedColor = Color.BLUE;

        @Override
        public void setAlpha(final int _i) {
        }

        @Override
        public void setColorFilter(final ColorFilter _colorFilter) {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isStateful() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean setState(final int[] stateSet) {
            final boolean res = super.setState(stateSet);
            invalidateSelf();
            return res;
        }

        @Override
        public int getOpacity() {
            return 255;
        }

        public void setRatingMaxLevelValue(final int _ratingMaxLevelValue) {
            ratingMaxLevelValue = _ratingMaxLevelValue;
        }

        public void setUnCheckedColor(final int _uncheckedColor) {
            uncheckedColor = _uncheckedColor;
        }

        public void setPressedColor(final int _pressedColor) {
            pressedColor = _pressedColor;
        }

        public void setCheckedColor(final int _checkedColor) {
            checkedColor = _checkedColor;
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(final Canvas _canvas) {
            boolean pressed = false;
            for (int i : getState()) {
                if (i == android.R.attr.state_pressed) {
                    pressed = true;
                }
            }

            final int level = (int) Math.ceil(getLevel() / (double) ratingMaxLevelValue * STAR_COUNT);
            final int starRadius = Math.min(getBounds().bottom / 2, getBounds().right / STAR_COUNT / 2);

            for (int i = 0; i < STAR_COUNT; i++) {
                final int usedColor;
                if (level >= i + 1) {
                    usedColor = checkedColor;
                } else if (pressed) {
                    usedColor = pressedColor;
                } else {
                    usedColor = uncheckedColor;
                }
                drawStar(_canvas, usedColor, (i * 2 + 1) * starRadius, getBounds().bottom / 2, starRadius,
                    STAR_BRANCHES_COUNT);
            }
        }

        private void drawStar(final Canvas _canvas, final int _color, final float _centerX, final float _centerY,
            final float _radius, final int _branchesCount) {
            final double rotationAngle = Math.PI * 2 / _branchesCount;
            final double rotationAngleComplement = Math.PI / 2 - rotationAngle;
            //Calculating how much space is left between the bottom of the star and the bottom of the circle
            //In order to be able to center the star visually relatively to the square when drawn
            final float bottomOffset = (float) (_radius - _radius * Math.sin(rotationAngle / 2) / Math.tan(
                rotationAngle / 2));
            final float actualCenterY = _centerY + (bottomOffset / 2);
            final Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(_color);
            paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
            final Path path = new Path();
            final float relativeY = (float) (_radius - _radius * (1 - Math.sin(rotationAngleComplement)));
            final float relativeX = (float) (Math.tan(rotationAngle / 2) * relativeY);
            final PointF a = new PointF(-relativeX, -relativeY);
            final PointF b = new PointF(0, -_radius);
            final PointF c = new PointF(relativeX, -relativeY);
            path.moveTo(_centerX + a.x, actualCenterY + a.y);
            _canvas.save();
            for (int i = 0; i < _branchesCount; i++) {
                path.lineTo(_centerX + b.x, actualCenterY + b.y);
                path.lineTo(_centerX + c.x, actualCenterY + c.y);
                rotationToCenter(b, rotationAngle);
                rotationToCenter(c, rotationAngle);
            }
            _canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
            _canvas.restore();
        }

        private void rotationToCenter(final PointF _point, final double _angleRadian) {
            final float x = (float) (_point.x * Math.cos(_angleRadian) - _point.y * Math.sin(_angleRadian));
            final float y = (float) (_point.x * Math.sin(_angleRadian) + _point.y * Math.cos(_angleRadian));
            _point.x = x;
            _point.y = y;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late answer but i hope it will help some folks.

```
<RatingBar
         android:id="@+id/rating"
         style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small"
         android:theme="@style/WhiteRatingStar"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_below="@+id/profil_name"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_4"
         android:rating="3" />
```

And here is what the WhiteRatingStar looks like

```
<style name="WhiteRatingStar" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small">
     <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

With this the stars will be coloured in white for example.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this link**

[Android RatingBar change star colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446270/android-ratingbar-change-star-colors/36297738#36297738)

set your style inside value/style(v-21);

Answer (score -1):

As the previous answer implies, it is not easy to change the color of the ratingbar. The stars are not programmatically drawn, they are images with fixed size and specific color gradients. To change the color you have to create your own star images with different colors then proceed to create your own drawable XML resource and pass it to the ratingsBar class using setProgressDrawable(Drawable d) or XML attribute android:progressDrawable.

Answer (score -2):

Just edit or add

```
<color name="colorAccent">#3b71c7</color>
```

in your resource value folder

Comment: this is not an answer as it will reflect on all app components that depend on the color accent.

Comment: this is not the optimal solution as it will override the other views color.