# Fail to parse xml when creating custom rating bar on android 2.2

Tags: android, xml, rating

I need read-only Rating Bar with custom images. I tried several methods to do this:
[Android RatingBar change star colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446270/android-ratingbar-change-star-colors)
and
[How to create Custom Ratings bar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800657/how-to-create-custom-ratings-bar-in-android).
In both cases there's an xml parsing problem.

I think it might be because of my android version - 2.2. Any suggestions?

Exception from logcat:

```
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #70: Error inflating class android.widget.RatingBar
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at kz.mobidev.kinozavr.MovieListAdapter.getView(MovieListAdapter.java:40)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:220)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1727)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:652)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:709)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1580)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1147)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1045)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.widget.RatingBar.(RatingBar.java:114)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  ... 32 more
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ratingbar_red.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02001f
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1697)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.widget.ProgressBar.(ProgressBar.java:178)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.(AbsSeekBar.java:61)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.widget.RatingBar.(RatingBar.java:84)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  ... 36 more
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.addLayer(LayerDrawable.java:185)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflate(LayerDrawable.java:156)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:788)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:729)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
02-25 15:16:51.713: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  ... 40 more
```

I took this code from [Android RatingBar change star colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446270/android-ratingbar-change-star-colors):
ratingbar_red.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background" android:drawable="@drawable/star_white" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress" android:drawable="@drawable/star_green" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress" android:drawable="@drawable/star_green" />
</layer-list>
```

and assigned this drawable ratingbar_red.xml to my ratingbar:

```
<RatingBar android:id="@+id/rbRating"
style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="120dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:progressDrawable="@drawable/ratingbar_red" />
```

Comment: put your code snippet also exception from logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ratingbar_red.xml
```

Is your retingbar.xml in res/drawable folder? Check it.