# how to change the color RatingBar depending on the number of stars?

Tags: android, android-controls

How do the following?

if RatingBar has 1-3 stars - red stars.
if RatingBar has 4 stars - yellow stars.
if RatingBar has 5 stars - green stars.

```
((RatingBar) layout.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar)).setProgress(Integer.parseInt(surveyBeans.get(section).get(position).getRate()));


<RatingBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar" android:stepSize="1" android:clickable="false"
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall" android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />
```

EDIT:

```
 @Override
    public View getItemView(int section, int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LinearLayout layout;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            layout = (LinearLayout) inflator.inflate(R.layout.item_survey, null);
        } else {
            layout = (LinearLayout) convertView;
        }
        ((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.questionSurvey)).setText(surveyBeans.get(section).get(position).getQuestion());
        RatingBar ratingBar = ((RatingBar) layout.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar));
        ratingBar.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(surveyBeans.get(section).get(position).getRate()));
        LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
        stars.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        stars.getDrawable(1).setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        ((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.commentSurvey)).setText(surveyBeans.get(section).get(position).getComment());

        return layout;
    }
```

working code after answering @Murtaza Hussain:

```
RatingBar ratingBar = ((RatingBar) layout.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar));
        ratingBar.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(surveyBeans.get(section).get(position).getRate()));
        LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
        if (ratingBar.getRating()<=3) {
            stars.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        }
        if(ratingBar.getRating()==4){
            stars.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        }
        if(ratingBar.getRating()==5){
            stars.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        }
```

Comment: Have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446270/android-ratingbar-change-star-colors

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
stars.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

OR

```
LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
        stars.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.starFullySelected), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        stars.getDrawable(1).setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.starPartiallySelected), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        stars.getDrawable(0).setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.starNotSelected), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

You can do this on

```
ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                boolean fromUser) {
            // This event is fired when rating is changed   
        }    
    });
```

From your code

```
 @Override
 public View getItemView(int section, int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     LinearLayout layout;
     if (convertView == null) {
         LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         layout = (LinearLayout) inflator.inflate(R.layout.item_survey, null);
     } else {
         layout = (LinearLayout) convertView;
     }
     ((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.questionSurvey)).setText(surveyBeans.get(section).get(position).getQuestion());

     RatingBar ratingBar = ((RatingBar) layout.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar));
     ratingBar.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(surveyBeans.get(section).get(position).getRate()));

     if (ratingBar.getRating() == 2f) {
         //change color of two stars
     } else if (ratingBar.getRating() == 3f) {
         //change color of three stars
     }

     LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
     stars.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
     stars.getDrawable(1).setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
     ((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.commentSurvey)).setText(surveyBeans.get(section).get(position).getComment());

     return layout;
 }
```

Comment: I do not need to change their meaning. It is set once and for all. I only need to display different stars. what you wrote - 3 stars if they are yellow. the other gray. if 2 stars - they are yellow - the others are gray. if the 5 stars - they are all yellow. I need anyway. if 1 or 2 or 3 stars - they are red, and the rest - gray. if 4 stars - 4 stars is yellow and one gray.if the 5 stars - all 5 - green

Comment: didnt get you. what do you want ?

Comment: if 1 or 2 or 3 stars - they are red, and the rest - gray. if 4 stars - 4 stars is yellow and one gray.if the 5 stars - all 5 - green

Comment: empty star always gray! full of stars - change color depending on how many

Comment: setOnRatingBarChangeListener fires when you change the rating. "rating" values indicates values in total, so you can change color in "setOnRatingBarChangeListener "

Comment: You can read more here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener.html about "setOnRatingBarChangeListener "

Comment: say it again. I do not change the rating! I have a list of several RatingBar and when I load it, it once data is loaded. Edit to change them and they can not be

Comment: Correctly. Edit your answer please.
1. My type int. if (ratingBar.getRating()<=3) {
2. extra code below

Comment: @Murtaza Khursheed Hussain what if I want R.color.starFullySelected and R.color.starPartiallySelected to be exactly the same colour? How do I reflect that?

Answer (score 0):

```
 android:progressBackgroundTint="#FFF"
    android:progressTint="@color/golden"
```

keep those both lines in RatingBar, active stars color will be golden. working for lollipop