# Android RatingBar: getProgressDrawable doesn't cast to right Class

Tags: android, ratingbar

I am using

[Android RatingBar change star colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446270/android-ratingbar-change-star-colors)

This line of code

```
    LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) rating_bar.getProgressDrawable();
```

works fine on my Nexus 4 emulator API v21.
When trying the same code on my Galaxy S4 API v19, I get the following error message:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintDrawableWrapper cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable
```

What is happening?

I am building with the latest build tools 22, my target API is 22 is as well.

Comment: The method might not be supported for API 19 then.  Are you just trying to get a drawable from an object and use it somewhere else?

Comment: I'm trying to recolor my rating bar using the code as outlined in the question quoted in my post. What's weird is that a month ago, this was working fine. I think this is due to updating the build tools, target sdk, support libraries or something

Comment: Indeed, something seems to have changed in the latest API/SDK update (22). All my styled rating bars that used to look fine on all Android versions now only look good on Lollipop and above. On anything less than API 21, they are broken horribly, with just one stretched star being rendered, regardless of the rating value.

Comment: Just did some digging and it seems that API 22 automatically uses the new TintRatingBar class, which does some crazy stuff to the drawables when running on API < 21. Since I had no time to research further, my only solution was to subclass the normal RatingBar and use it instead, which seems to solve the problem by preserving the normal RatingBar behavior.

Comment: @DimitrisKazakos, you're describing exactly what I had!! Can you please post on the question how you did subclass RatingBar?

Comment: @Stephane I'm having the same problem, it sucks. You were able to work on all versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is clearly explained in the error message :

```
TintDrawableWrapper cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable
```

The support lib creates a wrapper in order to handle retro compatibility, you just need to take it into account. Have a look at the lib implementation, it probably wraps around a `LayerDrawable`.

You will need to do something along the lines of :

```
LayerDrawable stars = getProgressDrawable(rating_bar);
}

private LayerDrawable getProgressDrawable(RatingBar ratingBar) {
  if (Build.VERSION >= LOLLIPOP) {
    return (LayerDrawable) ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
  } else {
    // fetch the LayerDrawable based on Google's support implementation,  
    // probably a simple findViewById()
  }
}
```

Comment: I have added some pointers, you will have to look at google's implementation in order to see how it is backported.

Comment: @Teovald Can you please show the support implementation? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @Gofilord : http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/internal/widget/TintDrawableWrapper.java
 is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: I meant what you actually put in the `else` to get the layer drawable on lower API levels.

Answer (score 0):

LayerDrawable is used in API v21.

Comment: user knows that well, he need  a fix for v22

Comment: but his Galaxy S4 API version is 19.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a subclass of RatingDialog and using that instead of`android.widget.RatingBar` worked for me.  Here is the code I used.

Subclass:

```
public class RatingBar extends android.widget.RatingBar {
public RatingBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

public RatingBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
}
```

Then in my layouts:

```
 <your.package.RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/rating_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    />
```

Then in the classes where you are casting the class, just use `your.package.RatingBar` instead of `android.widget.RatingBar`

Answer (score 0):

Came accross the same issue today when creating a RatingBar programmatically. The following workaround is working for me also on **Android 4.x** devices using the AppCompatRatingBar:

```
AppCompatRatingBar rb = new AppCompatRatingBar(activity);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
rb.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
rb.setStepSize(1.0f);
rb.setMax(5);

LayerDrawable layerDrawable = null;
if (rb.getProgressDrawable() instanceof LayerDrawable) {
    layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) rb.getProgressDrawable();
} else if (rb.getProgressDrawable() instanceof DrawableWrapper) {
    DrawableWrapper wrapper = (DrawableWrapper) rb.getProgressDrawable();
    if (wrapper.getWrappedDrawable() instanceof LayerDrawable) {
        layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) wrapper.getWrappedDrawable();
    }
}

if (layerDrawable != null) {
    layerDrawable.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    layerDrawable.getDrawable(0).setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    layerDrawable.getDrawable(1).setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.primary), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
}
```

Comment: (rb.getProgressDrawable() instanceof DrawableWrapper) always returns false

Answer (score 0):

Please try this trick, It will work fine by adding **getCurrent()** method to return a drawable.

RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);

LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) ratingBar.getProgressDrawable().getCurrent();

stars.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        stars.getDrawable(0).setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        stars.getDrawable(1).setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);