# ClassCastException: android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapperHoneycomb cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable

Tags: android, classcastexception, ratingbar

I'm trying to change `RatingBar` stars color but after migrating to Android API 23 my following codes don't work and give me an exception.

```
LayerDrawable ratingBarStars = (LayerDrawable) holder.ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
        ratingBarStars.getDrawable(0).setColorFilter(mContext.getResources()
                                                             .getColor(R.color.accent), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        ratingBarStars.getDrawable(1).setColorFilter(mContext.getResources()
                                                             .getColor(R.color.accent), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        ratingBarStars.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(mContext.getResources()
                                                             .getColor(R.color.accent), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

**And the Error is:**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapperHoneycomb cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable
```

Comment: obviously you cannot cast .... you should check if  `getProgressDrawable()` returns instance of `LayerDrawable` or `DrawableWrapper` from support library and then do other stuff based on those classes

Comment: @Selvin Above codes were working before migrating to API 23! I know I cannot cast but how to solve it? I need to change stars color.

Comment: question is: do you need this code at all .... it seems like they added ratingbar support in appcompat library ... so maybe it is already using accent color from AppCompat theme

Comment: @Selvin I changed to `AppCompatRatingBar` but nothing helped and same error.

Comment: **question is: do you need this code at all**!!! if they added support for this why are you trying to change it by your own ... comment this code and see what would happend

Comment: @Selvin Sorry I didn't understand you. Can you please give me an example of changing those stars color? Thanks.

Comment: `DrawableCompat.setTint(ratingBar.getProgressDrawable(), color)`

Comment: @Selvin Thank you so much. That worked like a charm. Please send your comment as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`DrawableCompat.setTint(ratingBar.getProgressDrawable(),color);` by Selvin in the comment section is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38207513/570168

tl;dr:

```
 layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) rb.getProgressDrawable().getWrappedDrawable();
```