# Cannot cast to LayerDrawable anymore (after upgrading v7)

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I'm using last version of the support libraries, 22.1.1.

I used to go like:

```
mRatingBar = (RatingBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.rating);
LayerDrawable layer = (LayerDrawable) mRatingBar.getProgressDrawable();
```

but after upgrading it crashes at line 2 with a `ClassCastException`:

```
android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapperHoneycomb cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:458)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
```

I'm testing on Android 4.2.2. Any hints & workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that `getProgressDrawable()` was not returning my `LayerDrawable` anymore.

I was setting a `LayerDrawable` background through style, with:

```
<item name="android:ratingBarStyle">@style/myRatingBarStyle</item>
```

Since v21.1 added a tint-aware version of the `RatingBar`, `AppCompatRatingBar`, they are now reading attributes from `ratingBarStyle`, rather than `android:ratingBarStyle`. So I had to replace the above line with:

```
<item name="ratingBarStyle">@style/myRatingBarStyle</item>
<item name="android:ratingBarStyle">@style/myRatingBarStyle</item> //API21+
```

Comment: what is myRatingBarStyle ? please complete your answer

Answer (score 5):

I got same issue. I searched for it and found that, If we write

```
<RatingBar
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:numStars="5"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

in XML file.   Than, Android by default convert RatingBar into, **android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRatingBar** instead of **android.widget.RatingBar**.

---

Just modify your code with below code and the issue will get solved.

```
<android.widget.RatingBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this one for set color of progressbar

`DrawableCompat.setTint(ratingBar.getProgressDrawable(),color);`

Answer (score 0):

When you're using AppCompat libraries many of your styles have not to include the **android:**, so the code above has this format:

```
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
<item name="android:ratingBarStyle">@style/myRatingBarStyle</item>
···

<!-- Support library compatibility -->
<item name="ratingBarStyle">@style/myRatingBarStyle</item> 
···
```

Basically you need to style for V21.1 and above and for compatibility, if you're styling several objects.