# how to change the rating star color in API 14

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, ratingbar

i have the following rating bar:

```
 final RatingBar rating = new RatingBar(mContext);
        rating.setStepSize(1);
        rating.setMax(5);
 }
```

Now I want to change the color for ratingbar for API 14.

I have write the following code:

```
rating.setProgressTintList(mContext.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.colorAccent));
```

But this is working with above API 21.

I want to set this color for API 14.

How can I do this?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446270/android-ratingbar-change-star-colors

Answer (score 0):

you can use this website to create color dependent widgets from this

http://android-holo-colors.com/

make your own style in for the Ratting or any other widget you want change  something in.  like this...

```
<style name="MyRatting" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/apptheme_spinner_background_holo_light</item>
 ..... keep changing desired items 
</style>
```

after this apply this style to the main style which your application is referencing to something like this

```
<style name="AppThemeTest" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

    <item name="android:ratingBarStyle">@style/MyRatting</item>
</style>
```

sometime the application may not be able to pick up your given style to the application for respective `Widget` in that case directly apply the style to the `Widget` something like this

```
<RatingBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/MyRatting"
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar" />
```