# Change ratingbar color in android

Tags: android, ratingbar

I implement the RatingBar in my android project its works perfectly but i want change the ratingbar filling color now defaultly it fill green color,but i want change into another color,
    below i attached my rating bar image,please any one help me how to change the color of rating bar, thanking you

```
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cN13.png


 **xml code:**

 <RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ratingAndReviewtext"
    android:isIndicator="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:rating="0.0"
    android:stepSize="0.0" />
```

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446270/android-ratingbar-change-star-colors

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**try following code programatically**

```
 RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
    LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
    stars.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Step #1: Create your own style, by cloning one of the existing styles
>   (from `$ANDROID_HOME/platforms/$SDK/data/res/values/styles.xml`),
>   putting it in your own project's `styles.xml`, and referencing it when
>   you add the widget to a layout.
>
> Step #2: Create your own `LayerDrawable` XML resources for the
>   `RatingBar`, pointing to appropriate images to use for the bar. The
>   original styles will point you to the existing resources that you can
>   compare with. Then, adjust your style to use your own `LayerDrawable`
>   resources, rather than built-in ones.

Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2447209/3891036

---

Rating Bar sample & Tutorial : http://www.skholingua.com/android-basic/user-interface/form-widgets/ratingbar