# Android: Color of stars in RatingBar, that already uses style

Tags: android, ratingbar

I want to change colour of RatingBar stars in every mode(highlighted, notHighlited, progress), but I already use style Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.

I don't want to change style cause, I like star shapes and staff, I only want to change star colors, Is it possible?

Here's my code:

```
<RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="1.0"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:rating="0.0" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446270/android-ratingbar-change-star-colors

Comment: `android:progressTint="@android:/color/black"`

Comment: For best way , You should use custom Ratingbar

Comment: progressTint is from api 21. i also saw that post, they offer to make my own style, but my question is diferrent, i already use style

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use styles:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background" android:drawable="@drawable/background" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress" android:drawable="@drawable/secondary_progress" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress" android:drawable="@drawable/progress" />
</layer-list>
```

You can use this style following way. Add this line to the RatingBar:

```
android:progressDrawable="@drawable/rating"
```