# Rating Bar Fill color android

Tags: android, ratingbar

For filling the color in rating bar for decimal rating is working fine for API below 23 and not working in API 23.

Here is the code:

```
RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.ratingbar);
ratingBar.setNumStars(5);
ratingBar.setMax(5);
ratingBar.setStepSize(0.1f);
ratingBar.setRating(0.5);
Drawable ratingBarColor = ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
DrawableCompat.setTint(ratingBarColor, ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.red));
```

which will fill the color for 0.5(half) star with the red color.
But for android API 23(MarshMallow) whatever you set the rating it's filling all the star.Can I know what's the change happened in API 23 which is causing this issue or let me know the problem with this code.

Handset used for testing  (6.0): HTC One M8, Moto X Play, Nexus 6.
5.1.1: Moto X(First Gen),Nexus 4,Moto G1,G2

Edit: I tested by removing setTint in API23 which is setting white color with decimal rating.So it could be issue with DrawableCompat for setting color for decimal rating star.

Comment: tried giving style? style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyle"??

Comment: @Viren I am setting custom rating bar progamatically.

Comment: I didn't get you. you are creating customized style??? I am telling you to declair it in the xml where ratingbar you placed.

Comment: @Viren Thanks.Does it make any difference?.

Comment: Hope so. Please put once.

Comment: @Viren for image it shows correctly.It's very difficult to make different color star image(I need to set star color based on some condition). My question is filling color inside the rating bar, which is failing.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446270/android-ratingbar-change-star-colors

Comment: @Viren.Thanks. But Please recheck my question. Filling color for rating bar is not reflecting in marshmalllow(API 23).

Answer (score 4):

For API 23(MarshMallow), RatingBar does suffer the problem of all stars changed color (regardless it's 1 or 5 stars) which look like it's always 5 stars.

**UPDATED ANSWER:**
The following code works

```
if (ratingBar.getProgressDrawable() instanceof LayerDrawable) {
    LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
    DrawableCompat.setTint(stars.getDrawable(2), color);
}
else {
    // for Android 4.3, ratingBar.getProgressDrawable()=DrawableWrapperHoneycomb
    DrawableCompat.setTint(ratingBar.getProgressDrawable(), color);
}
```

**The following doesn't work for Mashmallow**

```
Drawable ratingBarColor = ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
DrawableCompat.setTint(ratingBarColor, ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.red));
```

In the layout file remember to use android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRatingBar, not RatingBar.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Desmond. I will try it out.

Answer (score 2):

you can make the custom rating bar

1 just make the xml file in your drawable folder and name it **rating_bar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:id="@android:id/background" android:drawable="@drawable/rating_empty" />
        <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress" android:drawable="@drawable/rating_empty" />
        <item android:id="@android:id/progress" android:drawable="@drawable/rating_filled" />
    </layer-list>
```

2 make the another drawable xml file and name it **rating_empty.xml**

```
<item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:state_window_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/ic_unrated_star" />

<item android:state_focused="true"
      android:state_window_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/ic_unrated_star" />

<item android:state_selected="true"
      android:state_window_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/ic_unrated_star" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_unrated_star" />
```

3 make anothe drawable xml file for filled star and name it **rating_filled.xml**

```
<item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:state_window_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/ic_rated_star" />

<item android:state_focused="true"
      android:state_window_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/ic_rated_star" />

<item android:state_selected="true"
      android:state_window_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/ic_rated_star" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_rated_star" />
```

4 goto your values folder and open **style.xml** and add the style

```
<style name="customRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/rating_bar</item>
    </style>
```

5 just use the custom rating bar, which you have just created

```
    <RatingBar
    style="@style/customRatingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:numStars="5" />
```

**Note**: ***ic_rated_star*** and ***ic_unrated_star*** are the completly ***filled star*** and ***empty star*** image , which you want to show in your rating bar.

Hope this worked for you... best of luck...

Comment: How can you change the color of the rating bar based on conditions?. Please read the question before answering.