# Cannot change Android RatingBar's star color

Tags: android, ratingbar

The default color of AndroidBar star color is blue, like this:
[image]

I want to change the color into green. I've tried several ways, none of them works.

Using **android:progressTint**

```
<RatingBar
     android:id="@+id/rb"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:isIndicator="false"
     style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
     android:numStars="5"
     android:stepSize="1"
     android:progressTint="@color/green"
     android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Another attempt. Put a new style in styles.xml:

```
<style name="RatingBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/iron</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/green</item>
</style>
```

And apply it:

```
<RatingBar
     android:id="@+id/rb"
     android:theme="@style/RatingBar"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:isIndicator="false"
     style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
     android:numStars="5"
     android:stepSize="1"
     android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

My test device is an ASUS phone, running Android 4.4.2. Is there another way, which works on Android 4 and newer? Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21872331/3395198

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android RatingBar change star colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446270/android-ratingbar-change-star-colors)

Answer (score 0):

You need create two styles in the styles.xml files under values and v21.

Place this style in values/styles.xml file

```
 <style name="RatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.RatingBar">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Place this style in v21/styles.xml file

```
<style name="RatingBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Material.RatingBar">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

In your layout file, use the style like below:

```
<RatingBar
     android:id="@+id/rb"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:isIndicator="false"
     style="@style/RatingBar"
     android:numStars="5"
     android:stepSize="1"
     android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"` with `style="@style/RatingColor"`.
In `styles.xml`, add this:

```
<style name="RatingColor" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
  <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/blue</item>
  <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/green</item>
</style>
```